# Change radio button value in PrimeUi

Tags: jquery, prime-ui

I'm trying to set a `PuiRadioButton` to `checked` but I've encountered a problem. The underlying pure HTML input elements gets selected, but PrimeUI does not show the change.

I've the two elements:

```
<input type="radio" name="peopleSelection" id="peopleRadioButton" value="people" checked="checked" />
```

and

```
<input type="radio" name="peopleSelection" id="groupRadioButton" value="group" />
```

and I've tried following statement

```
$('#groupRadioButton').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

It works perfetly fine in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jH96b/3/). But when I inspect the HTML, the correct input element is checked successfully, but not shown by PrimeUI.

I also tried variations of these:

```
$('#groupRadioButton').prop('checked', true);
$('#groupRadioButton').attr('checked', 'checked');
$('#groupRadioButton')[0].checked = true;
```

Unfortunately I could not find a `set` or `get` method on the [PrimeUi Documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/radiobutton.html) page.

How do select/unselect PrimeUI radio buttons?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't use the library! Try triggering the `.change()` event after changing the property, `$('#groupRadioButton').prop('checked', true).change();`

Comment: I know. I just wanted to demonstrate the jquery code I used. I wasnt able to include primeui lib into the JSFiddle.

Comment: Thank you @BlackSheep. If you create an answer for that I'll accept it.